# Spring MVC form validation messages not loading

Tags: java, spring, validation, spring-mvc

I'm trying to define error messages in a resource file, but I can't seem to get them to load so I can use them in my controller.

My **servlet-context.xml** file:

```
<beans:bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <beans:property name="basename" value="classpath:messages" />
</beans:bean>
```

My **form**:

```
public class LoginForm {
    @NotEmpty
    private String username;
    // getters and setters
}
```

My **messages.properties** file (in the root of my source folder, so it gets compiled to the root of my classes folder):

```
NotEmpty.loginForm.username=test1
NotEmpty.username=test2
NotEmpty.java.lang.String=test3
NotEmpty=test4
```

My **controller**:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/login", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String login(@Valid LoginForm form, BindingResult result) {
    if (result.getFieldErrors().size() > 0) {
        FieldError firstError = result.getFieldErrors().get(0);
        System.out.println(firstError.getDefaultMessage());
    }
    // ...
}
```

However, the output of the `getDefaultMessage` call is never what I define in my resource file! It is always `may not be empty` (the default).

I've tried a variety of different entries in my context file but it seems like it's not loading the resource file. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why don't you set the `message` attribute of `@NotEmpty` and all other validation annotations?

Comment: I'd like to be able to control all resource message outside of the form bean, not only for decoupling but also to have a 'base message' for generic errors (i.e. for 'NotEmpty' code).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately it looks like a MessageSource must be defined and then used in the appropriate Java class. The `getDefaultMessage()` method doesn't appear able to read from message properties.

In a component-scanned class:

```
@Autowired
private MessageSource messageSource;
public String getMessage(FieldError field) {
    return messageSource.getMessage(field, null);
}
```

This will iterate through all possibilities in the message properties files and then--if nothing is found--falls back on the `getDefaultMessage()` results.

Additionally I updated my servlet-context.xml file to define my messageSource with the basename value of `/WEB-INF/classes/messages`, as opposed to what I had in my question above.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/validator/4.0.1/reference/en/html_single/#section-message-interpolation), all you need is to put a properties file called `ValidationMessages.properties` at the root of your project classpath.

You can then add properties with the following format

```
org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotEmpty.message=Default message, can not be empty 
NotEmpty.ClassName.fieldName=fieldName can not be empty.
```

where `ClassName` is the name of your class and `fieldName` is the name of the field of that class.

You might need to do some configuration to set the correct `MessageInterpolator`, but I think the default one will do what you need.

Comment: This is for hibernate validation, no? I'm asking about normal form validation.

Comment: @trebor Hibernate Validation is an implementation of Java's bean validation API.

Answer (score 0):

*First idea:*

Try to rename property keys from NotEmpty.loginForm.username to NotEmpty (Just to check if messageSource works correctly). If still not working there is

*Second idea:*

Where do you perform scanning of components?
Assume that you have two spring configurations: applicationContext.xml (or other name) and servlet-context.xml.

If you have such structure `<context:component-scan base-package="by.company.app" />` in applicationContext than your controllers have no defined messageSource - so it cannot load customized messages. It is because @Controller bean is in one spring context, MessageSource bean - in another. (To check this you can simple declare `@Autowired MessageSource messageSource` field in controller and see in debug is it null or not) In that case you can modify component-scan in applicationContext to:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by.company.app">
    <context:exclude-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

and add following configuration to servlet-context.xml:

```
<context:component-scan base-package="by" use-default-filters="false">
    <context:include-filter expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller" type="annotation"/>
</context:component-scan>
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time to fix this issue, I done a following changes, now it is working fine in Spring 4.0 MVC and Hibernate 4.1.9

1.put messages under source folder.

1. If ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource is not working change to

   class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
2. changes property like  '<'property name="basename" value="messages"/>
3. In Message.properties file, the key should be in the following format.

   NotEmpty.userForm.userId

   ```
   userForm-->Model class name.
   ```

(If your Model class name is UserForm, then it should
                                     be mentioned as userForm)

```
    userId--> attribute of userForm class
```

Comment: The application currently uses Spring MVC 3.2.2 but upgrading to 4.0.5 didn't solve the issue. In your controller, the BindingResult has the correct default message from the properties file? Additionally, try doing it without mapping a specific form property (instead of NotEmpty.userForm.userId, use the generic NotEmpty).